# Why is recursion taking so long?

Tags: c

In using recursion to calculate the  nth number of the fibonacci sequence, I have written this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned int long long fibonacci(unsigned int number);

//game of craps
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    for(int n = 1; n <= 100; n++)
    {
        printf("%llu\n", fibonacci(n));
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


unsigned long long int fibonacci(unsigned int number)
{
    if (number == 0 || number == 1)
    {
        return number;
    }
    else
    {
        return fibonacci(number - 2) + fibonacci(number - 1);      
    }
}
```

where each call to the n+1 number in the sequence doubles the number of function calls the program has to run.  Therefore the number of calls being made to the recursive function is something of 2^n, or exponential complexity.   Understood.  But where is all of the computing power going? once the nth number in the sequence starts to hit 40, the computer starts taking noticeable time to compute the result where at n = 47 its take 30+ seconds.  However my computer shows that I'm only using 21 percent of cpu power.  I'm using NetBeans IDE to run the program. It's a quad core system.

Comment: 21% is not that far from 25%, ie. 100% of the one core you can use.

Comment: If the question is why it's taking so long it's because it has to calculate each previous number.

Comment: It takes a long time because this is approach, although simple, is arguably the least efficient approach (double recursion) to doing fibonacci sequence calculations. It amount of recursion increases exponentially with the size of the number, and it recalculates values multi-fold.

Comment: thanks guys.  I understand that this approach isn't efficient; I was just curious why it wasn't using all cores.  I guess now I'll have to look into how to assign new threads in c.

Comment: That code is obviously sub-optimal and not how fib(n) is typically calculated (or defined, iirc). Maybe you should do at least some basic research.

Comment: Actually, just look up memoizing.  Good programming trumps faster hardware.

Answer (score 4):

> the number of calls being made to the recursive function is something of 2^n, or exponential complexity. Understood.

I'm not sure you do entirely understand this, since you seem surprised about how slow it becomes around n=40, and n=47.

With a complexity of 2^n, and an *n* of 40, that would be 2<sup>40</sup>, or 1,099,511,627,776, or about 1 *trillion* operations. If your computer can run about one of these operations per nanosecond, i.e. 1 billion operations per second, it would take 1000 seconds to finish.

Consider if *n* was only 30. 2<sup>30</sup> is 1,073,741,824, which would take only about 1 second to do on that same computer.

As has been mentioned, you're only using one core. You could parallelize, but that won't help much. Use four cores instead of one, and my n=40 example will still take 250 seconds. Go up to n=42 and you're back to 1000 seconds, because parallelizing *at best* multiplies your performance, but an algorithm like this grows exponentially.

Answer (score 2):

1. the posted code contains some extreme over complexity.
2. even a `long long unsigned int` cannot contain a Fibonacci value
   number 100 (or even close to it)

Suggest using a very simple program to start, one that calculates the Fibonacci sequence.  Then use that program to determine how to display the results.

The following program calculates the numbers, is very fast, but still has the problem of overflow of a `long long unsigned int`

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf()


int main( void )
{
    long long unsigned currentNum = 1;
    long long unsigned priorNum = 1;

    printf( "1\n1\n" );

    for (size_t i = 2;  i < 100; i++ )
    {
        long long unsigned newNum = currentNum+priorNum;
        printf( "%llu\n", newNum );
        priorNum = currentNum;
        currentNum = newNum;
    }
}
```

On my linux 86-64 computer, here are the last few lines of the output, showing the overflow problem.

```
99194853094755497
160500643816367088
259695496911122585
420196140727489673
679891637638612258
1100087778366101931
1779979416004714189
2880067194370816120
4660046610375530309
7540113804746346429
12200160415121876738
1293530146158671551
13493690561280548289
14787220707439219840
9834167195010216513
6174643828739884737
16008811023750101250
3736710778780434371
```

So, why is recursion taking so long?

because of the huge number of recursions and the handling of the overflows

The above suggested code eliminates the recursions, but not the overflows and it takes less than a second (on my computer) to run.

Comment: The *overflow* certainly hinders correctness, but from the point of view of complexity I don't see how it makes the computation any slower. Anyway, +1

Answer (score 1):

You won't exploit a quad core system if you have a single-threaded program.

It will run on one core only, so the 21/25% CPU usage is realistic.

A way to use it all would be, first of all not using recursion as it makes it annoying to do, and when you have a for/while loop split it into 4 while loops and put each of them in a new thread. Then you'll have to manage synchronization in order to print the message properly, but it's not even that hard. You could store all the results in an array and then print it when all the threads are done.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer made by @[user3629249](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3629249/user3629249), you can get rid of the *overflows* he mentioned by using the *infinite precision arithmetic library* provided by [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

**e.g.**

```c
#include <stdio.h>  // printf
#include <stdlib.h> // free
#include <gmp.h>    // mpz_t

int main( void )
{
    mpz_t prevNum, currNum, tempNum, counter;

    mpz_init_set_si(prevNum, 0);
    mpz_init_set_si(currNum, 1);
    mpz_init_set_si(tempNum, 1);
    mpz_init_set_si(counter, 1);

    printf( "0: 0\n" );

    while (1) {
        char *tempNumRepr = mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, tempNum);
        char *counterRepr = mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, counter);

        printf("%s: %s\n", counterRepr, tempNumRepr);

        free(tempNumRepr);
        free(counterRepr);

        mpz_add(tempNum, currNum, prevNum); // tempNum = currNum + prevNum;
        mpz_add_ui(counter, counter, 1);    // counter = counter + 1;
        mpz_set(prevNum, currNum);          // prevNum = currNum;
        mpz_set(currNum, tempNum);          // currNum = tempNum;
    }

    mpz_clear(prevNum);
    mpz_clear(currNum);
    mpz_clear(tempNum);
    mpz_clear(counter);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

To compile it, ensure that you have *libgmp* installed, type:

```
~$ gcc fib.c -lgmp
```

You get massive *fibonacci* values pretty fast:

```
~$ ./a.out
0: 0
1: 1
2: 1
3: 2
4: 3
5: 5
6: 8
7: 13
8: 21
9: 34
...
90: 2880067194370816120
91: 4660046610375530309
92: 7540113804746346429
93: 12200160415121876738
94: 19740274219868223167
95: 31940434634990099905
96: 51680708854858323072
97: 83621143489848422977
98: 135301852344706746049
99: 218922995834555169026
100: 354224848179261915075
...
142: 212207101440105399533740733471
143: 343358302784187294870275058337
144: 555565404224292694404015791808
145: 898923707008479989274290850145
146: 1454489111232772683678306641953
147: 2353412818241252672952597492098
148: 3807901929474025356630904134051
149: 6161314747715278029583501626149
150: 9969216677189303386214405760200
...
10456: 6687771891046976665010914682715972428661740561209776353485935351631179302708216108795962659308263419533746676628535531789045787219342206829688433844719175383255599341828410480942962469553971997586487609675800755252584139702413749597015823849849046700521430415467867019518212926720410106893075072562394664597041033593563521410003073230903292197734713471051090595503533547412747118747787351929732433449493727418908972479566909080954709569018619548197645271462668017096925677064951824250666293199593131718849011440475925874263429880250725807157443918222920142864819346465587051597207982477956741428300547495546275347374411309127960079792636429623948756731669388275421014167909883947268371246535572766045766175917299574719971717954980856956555916099403979976768699108922030154574061373884317374443228652666763423361895311742060974910298682465051864682016439317005971937944787596597197162234588349001773183227535867183191706435572614767923270023480287832648770215573899455920695896713514952891911913499762717737021116746179317675622780792638129991728650763618970292905899648572351513919065201266611540504973510404007895858009291738402611754822294670524761118059571137973416151185102238975390542996959456114838498320921216851752236455715812273599551395186676228882752252829522673168259864505917922994675966393982705428427387550834530918600733123354437191268657802903434440996622861582962869292133202292740984119730918997492224957849300327645752441866958526558379656521799598935096546592129670888574358354955519855060127168291877171959996776081517513455753528959306416265886428706197994064431298142841481516239689015446304286858347321708226391039390175388745315544138793021359869227432464706950061238138314080606377506673283324908921190615421862717588664540813607678946107283312579595718137450873566434040358736923152893920579043838335105796035360841757227288861017982575677839192583578548045589322945
...
```

Use *CTRL+C* to stop the program.

Comment: Thanks for the example for using the gmp library